# Redis cache read performance - root key/value pairs vs hierarchical structure?

Tags: performance, redis

Say I want to store user preferences...something simple like this:

```
{
    "favoriteColor": "green",
    "bestFriends": [
        "Tom",
        "Jenny",
        "Horton"
    ]
}
```

What's the best, most performant way to store this in redis cache (optimized for reads)?

Imagine UserId = 123

NOTE: Below I'm using the Redis documentation's way of representing the various structures. See [here](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro).

1. Simple, flat, key/value pairs right in the root?

   `user-123-favoriteColor = green (this is a STRING type)

   user-123-bestFriends = 
       1) "bestFriends" (SET TYPE)
       2) "Tom"
       3) "Jenny"
       4) "Horton"`
2. Hierarchical structure (hash of values)

   `user-123 = 
       1) "favoriteColor" (STRING type)
       2) "green"
       3) "bestFriends" (SET TYPE)
       4) "Tom"
       5) "Jenny"
       6) "Horton"`

And a related question...is there any reason not to store user preferences in redis vs the domain sql database?

And one more related question...is it a bad idea to store all users under one root key called "users"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the horses mouth](http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization#use-hashes-when-possible):

> **Use hashes when possible**
>   Small hashes are encoded in a very small space, so you should try representing your data using hashes every time it is possible. For instance if you have objects representing users in a web application, instead of using different keys for name, surname, email, password, use a single hash with all the required fields.
>   If you want to know more about this, read the next section.

So the answer is yes, use hashes where possible.

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810036/complex-data-structures-redis) is a good way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Hierarchical structure should be preferred.
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18991212/898431) gives a lot of explanation and helped me.